# Retornar quantidade desejavel

Tags: php

Boa noite, como posso retornar valores de uma array de acordo com o valor de uma variável ? Já tentei desta forma (sem sucesso):

O objetivo seria retornar a quantidade desejada (informada no GET de retornar)de elementos de um array

```
localhost/estudo.php?retornar=5
$retornar = $_GET['retornar'];
for ($i=0; $i < $retornar ; $i++) { 
$ccs = $ccs[$i];
echo $ccs;
}
```

Comment: Poste o código completo, pelo que estou vendo falta a parte do array.

Comment: Não precisa converter o `$retornar` para inteiro https://3v4l.org/Ke6Cu (como falaram abaixo). O erro é que você está substituindo o *array* `$ccs` na linha `$ccs = $ccs[$i];`

Comment: @ValdeirPsr eu incorporei seu comentário, mas se preferir responda em separado, e eu retiro da minha, que o +1 é garantido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente não recomendo utilizar esse tipo de modelo, a não ser que seja para caso de estudo.

Segundo, mesmo que seja para estudo recomendo aplicar algumas lógicas:

1. Iterar apenas se o retorno for maior que um (1)
2. Verificar se o valor passado não ultrapassa a quantidade de elementos
3. Converter para `inteiro`, garantido que o usuário digite um número válido
4. Verificar se o valor passado é um número

Inicialmente, aplicando de acordo com seu código, segue modelo atualizado;

```
$retornar = 5; //(int)$_GET['retornar'];

$ccs = array("1", "2"); //código novo (já que você não postou a linha referente ao array)

for($i = 0; $i < $retornar; $i++) { 
    echo $ccs[$i];
}
```

Veja em funcionamento https://3v4l.org/YOSLU

### Alterando para forma recomendada

> Utilizo 0 para verificar se foi selecionado 1, porque o array inicia em 0, para isso basta alterar o laço de repetição para 1

```
<?php

$retornar = 5; //$_GET['retornar'];

$ccs = array("1", "2");

if($retornar > count($ccs)){
    die("Quantidade indisponivel");
}

if($retornar == 0){
    echo $ccs[0];
}else{
    for($i = 0; $i < $retornar; $i++) { 
        echo $ccs[$i];
    }
}
```

Veja em funcionamento https://3v4l.org/ntcpZ

Essa nova forma não está 100% referente as informações, fica para você tentar fazer, já que o tópico em si já foi respondido.

Comment: Não precisa converter o `$retornar` para inteiro https://3v4l.org/Ke6Cu

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigada.

Answer (score 4):

A resposta correta é o comentário do colega ValdeirPsr. Você está estragando o *array* no loop:

```
for ($i=0; $i < $retornar ; $i++) { 
   $ccs = $ccs[$i];
   echo $ccs;       // Na segunda iteração, a linha anterior vai falhar
}
```

Bastaria mudar o nome da variável, ou usar o índice já no `echo`:

```
for ($i=0; $i < $retornar ; $i++) { 
   $ccs2 = $ccs[$i];
   echo $ccs2;
}
```

### Alternativa

Se não fosse um exercício, e sim uma aplicação real, poderia usar o que já vem pronto no PHP, em uma linha só:

```
print_r( array_slice( $ccs, 0, $_GET['retornar'] );
```

Ou mesmo

```
$pedaco = array_slice( $ccs, 0, $_GET['retornar'] );
foreach ($pedaco as $key=>$value) { 
   echo $value;
}
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/njcVXc)**

O `array_slice` retorna um *array* extraido de outro, determinado por um *offset* e um *comprimento*.

Manual:

> https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-slice.php